# Trigger keydown event on mousescroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

On `div`, with `overflow-y: scroll`,  how can I scroll down with `keypress` `down` (no jQuery).

```html
<div class="data">
    ...
    number of data
</div>
<style>
    .data {
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        margin-left: 700px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        height: 400px;
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/SahilKatia/pen/GYVzxR

Link to the [Angular Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown1?file=app%2Fdropdown-manual.html).

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your question. You want to trigger a key down event on mousescroll, without using a select, by using keyboard events?

Comment: Please check now, I edited my question, also check codepen link

Comment: If I click on an option in the select in codepen, I can then use down arrow to scroll down (in firefox at least)

Comment: without clicking, mouseScroll works but keypress down not

Comment: that's because the "page" does not have the focus.  Perhaps a javascript focus to the select box on page load will do the job

Comment: Actually, here I am directly showing the data, in our application we are using it as dropdown, so at this moment I am not able to change whole HTML, but I can modify it

Comment: @Graham any other way? like on hover it can focus the div?

Comment: On the "click me" - also add a focus after you show the dropdown

Comment: you could do it on mouseover (hover) too

Comment: Thanks, let me try focus on click, I didn't get mouseover(hover) if possible can you edit stackblitz?

Comment: @Graham I tried focus but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you add the attribute `tabindex="0"` to your `.data` div, that will make it "focusable" and let you scroll up and down with the keyboard when it is focused.

I'm assuming you only want the keyboard arrows to scroll your div when it's in focus, otherwise you'd have to override the existing full window scroll functionality like this:

```
const dataDiv = document.querySelector('body > div.data')
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataDiv.scrollTo(0, dataDiv.scrollTop - 10)
  } else if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataDiv.scrollTo(0, dataDiv.scrollTop + 10)
  }
})
```

Comment: tried tabindex too, but no luck
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown1-zrdtjr?file=app%2Fdropdown-manual.html

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is the functionality you are looking for. Building on the note from @Graham you can javascript to set focus on the .data div on page load, allowing the user to scroll the table using key up/down without an initial click.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("auto-focus").focus();
};
```

```css
.data {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:700px;
  text-align:center;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:400px;
  background-color:blue;
  width:150px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="data" tabindex="0" id="auto-focus">
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Octavius</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Amal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Hayes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Arsenio</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Jackson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chadwick</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chaim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kennedy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Oliver</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Vincent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Giacomo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Sebastian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Oren</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Perry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Jesse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Laith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kirk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Christopher</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Oren</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Donovan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chandler</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rajah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lyle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rogan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Colt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rooney</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Cruz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Connor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Walter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Roth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Adam</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Roth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kibo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Sebastian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lawrence</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Valentine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Dorian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Yuli</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Matthew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Wang</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Elton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Chadwick</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kibo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Reuben</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rashad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kibo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Orlando</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Amir</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>William</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lester</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Timon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>William</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Dale</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Timothy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lyle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Erasmus</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Amos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Dexter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Malcolm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Hyatt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Sawyer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Elton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kennan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Alec</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Prescott</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Omar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Jason</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Ignatius</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Isaac</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Aidan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gabriel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Brody</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Emerson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Burton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Axel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Clinton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Abdul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Philip</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Harding</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Lee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Denton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Kevin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Rashad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Davis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Hasad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Nehru</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Galvin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Isaiah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Fritz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Wallace</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Barclay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Harding</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Dieter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Emmanuel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Burke</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Caesar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Randall</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Seems this also doesn't work for me because it works once on load, if user does other things and then try this functionality it will not work

Comment: Is your aim to have the mouse up / down keys move this specific div no matter what the user is doing on your site or is there a more specific set of instances in which user's would focus on this functionality?